# Using python output xml

Tags: python, xml

Yesterday i have asked similar question like this about output xml by using python. But today i want to use the python code to display the XML content of the **restaurant name and capacity for rate larger than 4**. Here is xml my code

```
<record>
   <restaurant name="La Pasteria" rate="3">
      <cuisine id="-">Italian</cuisine>
      <address>8, Jalan Mata Kuching, 89200 Selangor</address>
      <capacity>300</capacity>
      <phone>06-2899808</phone>
      <phone>06-2829818</phone>
         <general>-</general>
         <shop1>-</shop1>
         <shop2>-</shop2>
   </restaurant>
   <restaurant name="Nyonya Baba" rate="5">
      <cuisine id="112">Malaysian</cuisine>
      <address>21, Jalan Taming Sari, 75350 Melaka</address>
      <address>25, Jalan Bukit Beruang, 75450 Melaka</address>
      <capacity>80</capacity>
      <phone>
      <general>012-2677498</general>
         <shop1>06-2855413</shop1>
         <shop2>06-2856418</shop2>
      </phone>
</record>
```

Here is what i am using in python

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 
# We're at the root node (<page>)
root_node = ET.parse('record.xml').getroot()

# We need to go one level below to get <items>
# and then one more level from that to go to <item>
for tag in root_node.findall('restaurant'):
    value = tag.attrib['name']
    print("Restaurant name:")
    print(value)
    for capacity in tag.findall('capacity'):
        print(capacity.text)
```

What i need to add inside this code to output if the restaurant rate is larger than 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you had to do was to check if the rate is larger than 4

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 
# We're at the root node (<page>)
root_node = ET.parse('record.xml').getroot()

# We need to go one level below to get <items>
# and then one more level from that to go to <item>
for tag in root_node.findall('restaurant'):
    if int(tag.attrib.get("rate", 0)) > 4:
        value = tag.attrib['name']
        print("Restaurant name:")
        print(value)
        for capacity in tag.findall('capacity'):
            print(capacity.text)
```